# Особенности использования альтернативных аллокаторов памяти

Tags: c++

```
Linear Allocator
Stack Allocator
Pool Allocator
Free list Allocator
```

Когда стоит использовать данные аллокаторы?

Какой из данных аллокаторов являет собой `std::allocator`?

Comment: Похоже на собеседование. Хорошая тема что б "пригрузить".